# SSRS Large Report -- Error When Exporting to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services

We are having an issue when exporting a large SSRS report to Excel. We receive the following error when it is run over a three-year date range. If the report is run for each of the years separately, the error does not occur.

> "We found a problem with some content in 'ReportName.xlsx'. Do you
>   want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source
>   of this workbook, click yes."

After clicking yes, the file opens, but it doesn't look usable.

What is the fix for this error, other than running the report for a year at time?

I have changed the report's timeout to "Do not timeout report" in Report Manager, but that has no effect.

Comment: How many rows of data is it trying to put in the Excel file? The limits are 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns

Comment: What you could do is, if your report is generating more than the limits of Excel, you could add a page break after each year. Excel will create new sheets for each page. So there will be 3 sheets on Excel, one for a year

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur on reports of any size. The issue can be caused by the scale or precision of the datatypes of the output columns. I think the limit in Excel is 20 digits (plus a decimal point) so you could cast your decimal values to say `decimal (14,6)` and this will solve this particular issue.

You could also have issues as others have stated if you exceed the maximum rows/columns allowed in Excel. This is dependant on the version of SSRS you are using as older versions render the older Excel version files (Excel 97-2003 I think but could be wrong). later version (SSRS2012 I think) render the newer XLSX (Excel 2007 ->) format.